# Handling error using Android paging library

Tags: android, android-paging

I am trying to make a simple list fragment by using paging library. The document said if I want to refresh the entire list, I should use `invalidate` method in DataSource. When I call this method, a new `DataSource` will be created and method `loadInitial` will be called, but if I encounter an error in `loadInitial`, for example, I load remote data from network, it's very common to meet an network error, then I need to call `loadInitial` again when I need to retry. But after I calling `invalidate`, the all my old data in the list are cleared because paging library give me a new empty `PagedList`. Even if I wait until the new list is not empty, the old list can not load next page because it have bean already invalided.

What should I do if I want to keep my old list working when invalidate the `DataSource` but encounter an error?